# Postgres db dump/restore error

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to dump/restore a database between servers. Here is what I have tried is

DUMP:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U user database > dump.sql
```

Restore Onto other server:

```
createdb -h localhost -U postgres -T template0 database
psql -d database -U postgres -h localhost -f dump.sql

psql:rocdocs.sql:35: ERROR:  could not access file "/usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/lib/liblwgeom": No such file or directory
psql:rocdocs.sql:38: ERROR:  function public.st_box2d_in(cstring) does not exist
psql:rocdocs.sql:46: ERROR:  could not access file "/usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/lib/liblwgeom": No such file or directory
psql:rocdocs.sql:49: ERROR:  function public.st_box2d_out(box2d) does not exist
psql:rocdocs.sql:61: ERROR:  function st_box2d_in(cstring) does not exist
```

...
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by lack of PostGIS shared libraries.

In general, to guarantee successful restore, you should have installed all the same extensions/contrib modules/addons/extras, which were installed in the primary server. This will guarantee that all shared libraries are in place.

Install PostGIS (same version) in the server, and retry.

See

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413600/no-liblwgeom-when-using-postgresql84-and-postgis-on-snow-leopard-with-macports (reported on a Mac but applies to your problem)
- http://www.postgis.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-October/027988.html
  *

PS. You did not specify your PostgreSQL / PostGIS version, this is needed if you need more help.